# How to add a virtual directory name in URL after domain name which actually not exists

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to add a virtual directory after domain name depending on user's response in my site. Suppose User select their country as USA, the url would be www.domain.com/US/ for rest of the visit for the user, for Germany it wold be www.domain.com/DE/ etc.....

In this cases the US or DE are not exist in real, only it will show in the URL, but the control will point the actual directories.

Please help

Comment: You can use mod_rewrite, and for example both dirs "US and DE" retrieve the same index.php file, but change the url aspect. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks juanbits for your help. Actually I'm new in rewrite rules and can't find exact solution in the above link. I mean, I've to just ignore the first element in url though it will be there. in the e.g. domain.com/US/files/index.php will point domain.com/files/index.php. Many thanks